# Find out where $PATH got corrupted

Tags: bash, shell, osx, path

I'm using OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.2

`$echo $PATH` prints this:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Users/myusername/.rvm/bin
```

I've commented out everything in `~/.bash_profile` and `~/.bashrc` and restarted the computer, but the last part in the `$PATH` variable(`/Users/myusername/.rvm/bin`) does not go away.

How can I find out where that last part gets added to my `$PATH` variable?

Comment: Did you restart current shell after changes in config files?

Comment: yes, I've restarted the Terminal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`man bash`'s `INVOCATION` section explains which files are involved in starting an interactive login shell session:

- `/etc/profile`
- `~/.bash_profile`
- `~/.bash_login`
- `~/.profile`

Any of these could contain this assignment or a `source` / `.` statement to source another script which contains this assignment. Since you've already checked the last two, try looking into the first two and any files that any of these source. This typically includes **`/etc/profile.d/*`**, which often contains application-specific `PATH` assignments.

In my specific case (Ubuntu 12.10) these four files source the following:

- `/etc/profile`:

  - `/etc/bash.bashrc`
  - `/etc/profile.d/*.sh`
- `~/.bash_profile` doesn't exist
- `~/.bash_login` doesn't exist
- `~/.profile`:

  - `$HOME/.bashrc`

**RVM specifically** [requests that you source its RC file in `~/.bash_profile`](https://rvm.io/rvm/install/) for a single user installation, so that's probably a good bet.